# Csharp Twitter API with all twitter features

Tags: c#, twitter

I want to make website that do every things without twitter.com

I want see and reply twitter account tweets,DM,Mentions,Reply...are there any C# twitter API that include this features?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi. Tweetinvi is a C# library for Twitter that contains with very few exceptions all the features provided by Twitter as well as various tools that will simplify your development.

The library has been developed with various Twitter developers to help them in their various usages of the Twitter REST and Stream APIs.

You can watch a short introduction video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1maeTudF8cQ.

- You can find Tweetinvi at https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi.
- The documentation at : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Introduction

Enjoy!

Comment: it looks very good.I will try this.Tweetinvi support see DM and send DM? Tweettinvi support get mentions?Can I see tweets Statistics?

Comment: You can check the documentation for direct messages at https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Messages. I don't understand what you mean by Tweet Statistics though.

Comment: I tried this code  :https://i.hizliresim.com/LyLdb0.png  sometimes it work give me DM lists sometimes it give below error.It give null credentials exception.What is problem with my code? 
 Tweetinvi.Exceptions.TwitterNullCredentialsException

Comment: You need to set your usercredentials `Auth.SetUserCredentials(userCreds)`

Comment: Really thankful for this comment and this library, it helped me a lot

Comment: Unfortunately the library stores data on threads extensively, which makes it completely unusable in web applications. Such a strange choice.

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin you are right. This is changing as per version 5.0 which is coming in few weeks.

Comment: @EgorPavlikhin please note that Tweetinvi 5.0 is now in alpha and available here : https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetinviAPI/5.0.0-alpha-1. New version of the documentation is also available here : https://linvi.github.io/tweetinvi